# htaccess rewrite breaks only on a specific URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^dev/(.*)/$ /out.php?q=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^dev/(.*)/([a-z]+)$ /out.php?q=$1&s=$2 [B,L]
```

URL request:

```
http://example.com/dev/100%25%20Booster%20Juice%20(6%20Hours)/supply
```

For some reason, the above request results in a server error while these:

```
http://example.com/dev/100%25%20Booster%20Juice%20(6%20Hours)/
http://example.com/dev/Energy%20Juice%20(6%20Hours)/supply
http://example.com/dev/Energy%20Juice%20(6%20Hours)/
```

work flawlessly and do not generate an error. I have no idea why it's just that one specific URL that doesn't work.

Comment: What is the server error?

Comment: Why don't you give some examples of the mapped URL to be able to understand what you want. Too much guesswork without them.

Comment: So this is kind of embarrassing...

It turns out that PHP wasn't properly parsing the URI and that the % was producing some weird output. I fixed it by manually encoding the URI.

@faa, it mapped out to out.php?q=Energy Juice (6 Hours)&s=supply

Comment: ¿But, do you still have problems with `http://example.com/dev/100%25%20Booster%20Juice%20(6%20Hours)/supply`? If so, the one in your comment is not it's mapped version. There is no `Energy juice`, for example, in the URL with the problem.